# Can POST vars be submitted in a user chosen encoding? (non UTF-8)

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a log in script and i was wondering if it's possible for someone to post characters other than UTF-8 to my script. My reason is i know MySQL's function: mysql_real_escape_string is 100% effective on UTF-8 but not sure on other encoding.

If this is a PHP.ini kind of thing, what's it called?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if a user overrides the character encoding set by the page (i.e. `View->Character Encoding->xxxxx` in Firefox), then the data POSTed will use that encoding. However, there is a very small list of characters that can be used to perform a SQL injection attack, and I think `mysql_real_escape_string` takes care of those - input encoding shouldn't matter, it's about how MySQL interprets the characters.